# How to throw an exception inside a Lambda?

Tags: java

How do you throw an exception inside a lambda e.g in `ifPresentOrElse` of a Optional?

```
try {
   foo.bar(baz).ifPresentOrElse(theBar -> { 
      // A code inside here needs to throw a custom exception so the outside can handle it
      // It can't throw atm, and it is an unhandled exception here
   }, () -> { response.set(notFound()); }
} catch(CustomException e) {
  somethingImportantWhenExceptionIsThrown();
}
```

Comment: Why not use [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-)?

Comment: I mean I need it to throw from inside, the the `bar` method to throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/):

And have the method wrapping this function annotated with `SneakyThrows`, as such:

```
@SneakyThrows
void method() {
   try {
       foo.bar(baz).ifPresentOrElse(theBar -> { 
          throw()
       }, () -> { response.set(notFound()); }
   } catch(CustomException e) {
      somethingImportantWhenExceptionIsThrown();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Altough not explicitly mentioned in your question, i am going to assume that you intent to throw a checked exception from `ifPresentOrElse`.

First, you should try to understand *why* you cannot throw an exception. The `Consumer` interface has, as `Runnable`, only a single abstract method, which makes it a `@FunctionalInterface`. From the documentation:

> Note that instances of functional interfaces can be created with
> lambda expressions, method references, or constructor references.

This is a reduced version of the `Consumer` interface:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {

    void accept(T t); // <-- NO throws Exception
}
```

Alternatively, you can still use the old anonymous inner class:

```
Consumer<Object> consumer = new Consumer<>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object o) { // <-- NO throws Exception
       // consume
    }
};
```

Therefore, you *cannot* throw a checked exception from the `accept` method. It is not possible by design. You can, however, chose one of the following options:

- Use a custom `ThrowingConsumer` and `ThrowingOptional` class, which can throw exceptions (since you declare them in their method signatures), not recommended.
- Wrap the checked exception in a `RuntimeException`, which does not need to be declared in the method signature, and can therefore be thrown.
- Rewrite your code to not use the lambda expression.

Example, for the last point:

```
Optional<Bar> barOpt = foo.bar(baz);
if(bar.isPresent()) {
    Bar bar = barOpt.get();
    try {
        // code that throws checked exception
    } catch(CustomException e) {
        somethingImportantWhenExceptionIsThrown();
    }
} else {
    response.set(notFound());
}
```

Comment: 4) Use the _hack_ provided by @quarks, but it is up to you if you want to use Lombok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with apache commons-lang3 library.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/function/Failable.html

```
Optional.of(obj).ifPresentOrElse(Failable.asConsumer(theBar -> {
    throw new Exception();
}), () -> {});
```